# Jquery or css highlight div on anchor jump/scroll

Tags: jquery, anchor

I am trying to highlight div by clicking on anchor link. What I mean is if I click on `<a href="$id1" class="scroll">My link</a>`

than it scroll to `<div id="id1">here</div>` On this page I have lots of anchor links and div so it is very confusing to identify on which div then scrolled so better to highlight border on  clicked anchor div. I tried below code but it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        // anchor click jump scroll
        jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {

            jQuery(".scroll").click(function(event){        
                event.preventDefault();
                jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
            });
        });

        jQuery(".scroll").click(function() {
           jQuery("#post-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>").css("border", "1px solid #ff0000").delay(1000).css("border", "none");
        };
    </script>
```

I am not sure if it does required jquery ui or just jquery is enough

Comment: It does not requires jQuery UI but only jQuery. But I don't understand why you subscribe to the `click` event twice moreover at 2 different moment (one inline and the other when the DOM is ready).

Comment: Because I am not expert and just trying to learn jquery so don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh ok, I think I get what you want to do: you want to scroll to the referenced element in the link and apply a style to this element (BTW, it is an `#` in the `<a href="#id1">`).

The code should then rather be :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".scroll").click(function(event){
        var $target = jQuery(this.hash);

        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$target.offset().top}, 500);
        $target.css("border", "1px solid #ff0000").delay(1000).css("border", "none");
    });
});
```

*Edited in order to use `jQuery` rather than `$`.*

Comment: Thanks for update but now it is behaving some weird. Sometime it scroll and some time jump and when its scroll not highlighting but when jump it does

Comment: Hum, strange... But perhaps, the animation should be only on `html` (and not on body too...).

Comment: I tried but now stops to react at all. I can't understand what is wrong in it. :(

Comment: Hum, in fact, it is the `delay` which works only on queued effects and not on css styles. For such case, you should you use native `setTimeout`. I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/YPs7j/).

Comment: I really appreciate your help but updated code at `jsfiddle` has stops to scroll. However it is highlighting border

Comment: In fact, you need both `html`and `body` : `body` does not work for FF but `html` does not work for Chrome... [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/YPs7j/1/).

Comment: Your code is working just fine but when I add to my files it is not at all working I don't know what is wrong with my files. Is that WordPress causing the issue or some other javascripts. I am changing all `$` to `jQuery` for no-conflict in wordpress

Answer (score 7):

Consider using `:target` CSS pseudo element -

[**Demo**](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/css3-target/document.html)

[**Demo with img:target**](http://jsfiddle.net/H8qFw/)

[**Check Browser Compatibility**](http://caniuse.com/#search=:target)

Comment: This is good idea but it is not working on IMG I have wrote css like `img:target` is that right?

Comment: Ah! so here is one more confusion. either you are using jquery or only css?

Comment: Okay I found the issue for CSS not jquery. I mean when I am using stroller for target it is not considering css and so I must have to change css through jquery

Comment: Great CSS only solution!